# Calculate SUM of many columns in many rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum

I want to calculate the sum of values in cell A1+B1+C1+D1+E1+F1. This calculation should be done in 100 rows. I want to use only one formula.

This Arrayformula is working, but is there a way to write it shorter? If you have more rows, the formulae gets very long.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A100 + B1:B100 + C1:C100 + D1:D100 + E1:E100 + F1:F100)`

The following one is not working, because it calculates the sum line by line. It sums all values in the whole table.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:F)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`BYROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) function:

```cpp
=BYROW(A1:F,LAMBDA(row,SUM(row)))
```

If you want to return a blank cell if the corresponding row has no values, you can use the following formula:

```cpp
=BYROW(A1:F,LAMBDA(row,IF(COUNTA(row)=0,,SUM(row))))
```